# MSbuild Package via Command line not including all my Assemblies

Tags: c#, msbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to setup a deploy script to do a publish of our website rather than have to open VS to do a deploy/publish.

When i do a publish via VS it will include all referenced assemblies correctly however when I do it via the command line it will not.  I am at a lose for what I am missing

My MSBuild command is:

```
msbuild "myproject.csproj" /T:Package;ResolveReferences /P:Configuration=Debug
/P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True    
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /P:WebProjectOutputDire="PreCompiled"
```

Comment: Please post the myproject.csproj as well.

Comment: Have you tried /T:Build;Package

Comment: @Jesse - I tried the /T:Build option and that still did not work.

Comment: @Daniel - the proj is massive and has our company name all over it so i cannot post it.  Sorry.

Comment: @DerikWhittaker How about `msbuild "myproject.csproj" /T:Rebuild;Package`

Comment: There's a similar question that got answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768998/the-entity-framework-resource-files-are-not-built-as-part-of-the-build-script#comment18996128_13768998