# The Entity Framework resource files are not built as part of the build script

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I have a batch file that builds an ASP.NET web application project, but it's not taking in the Entity Framework resource files in the Core Compile process.

The build script is:

```
set proj_name=MyProject
set proj_path=C:\...\path-to-project\
set pkg_name=MyProject.zip
set build_config=Release
set platform=AnyCPU
set msbuild=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

%msbuild% "%proj_path%%proj_name%.csproj"  /t:package /p:OutPath="%proj_path%obj" /p:OutputPath="%proj_path%bin" /p:Configuration=%build_config% /p:Platform=%platform%
```

While the script completes without errors, but the web app crash with `Unable to load the specified metadata resource` error.

But if I do a `Visual Studio Publish`, everything works fine. So that points me to look into my build output.

After carefully comparing the `Visual Studio Publish` output and my build script output, I found in the `CoreCompile` section, the `csdi`, `msl` and `ssdl` files are missing from my build script output. But the files are there on the file system and part of the `Solution` and `Project`. So I'm not sure why they are not included during the build. Below, is part of the build output:

Visual Studio Publish output:

```
/debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\Dnr.MotorPool.dll 
/resource:obj\Release\edmxResourcesToEmbed\DataAccess\MyDataModel.csdl,DataAccess.MyDataModel.csdl 
/resource:obj\Release\edmxResourcesToEmbed\DataAccess\MyDataModel.msl,DataAccess.MyDataModel.msl 
/resource:obj\Release\edmxResourcesToEmbed\DataAccess\MyDataModel.ssdl,DataAccess.MyDataModel.ssdl 
/target:library 
/utf8output all the cs files...
```

My build script output:

```
/debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\Dnr.MotorPool.dll 
/target:library 
/utf8output all the cs files...
```

So clearly, there are 3 missing files. How do I modify my build script then?

Comment: try `/t:ResolveReferences;package`

Comment: @KMoraz, I changed the build script to `%msbuild% "%proj_path%%proj_name%.csproj"  /t:ResolveReferences;package /p:OutPath="%proj_path%obj" /p:OutputPath="%proj_path%bin" /p:Configuration=%build_config% /p:Platform=%platform%` but the missing files are still missing.

Comment: @KMoraz, I got it working by using your suggestion (`/t:rebuild:package`) in another post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633408/msbuild-package-via-command-line-not-including-all-my-assemblies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%msbuild% "%proj_path%%proj_name%.csproj" /T:Rebuild;Package
```